# node.js POST empty req.body

Tags: node.js, express

I'm having trouble when I store data to MySQL database. I get a return in console blank.like this {}

here's route code :::`app.post('/create', employeeController.create);`

this is my controller code

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {

console.log((req.body));
const new_employee = new Employee(req.body);
//handles null error
if(req.body.constructor === Object && Object.keys(req.body).length === 0){
  res.status(400).send({ error:true, message: 'Please provide all required field' });
}else{
    Employee.create(new_employee, function(err, employee) {
      if (err)
      res.send(err);
      res.json({error:false,message:"Employee added successfully!",data:employee});
    });
}
};
```

this is my model code:

```
var db = require('../database');
//Employee object create
var Employee = function(employee){
this.name = employee.name;
this.email = employee.email;
this.position = employee.position;
};

Employee.create = function (newEmp, result) {
db.query("INSERT INTO employee set ?", newEmp, function (err, res) {
if(err) {
console.log("error: ", err);
result(err, null);
}
else{
console.log(res.insertId);
result(null, res.insertId);
}
});
};

module.exports= Employee;
```

my view code:

```
<form action="/create" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<label>Name</label>
<input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" required>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<label>Email</label>
<input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" required>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Position</label>
<input name="position" type="text" class="form-control" required>
</div>

</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
<br><br>

</form>
```

Im getting {} in log it means req.body is getting blank.

i have tried in app.js

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '100mb',extended: false }));
```

but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))` before your `app.use(bodyParser.json());`, and remove `app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '100mb',extended: false }));`.

```js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Then remove `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form. Because your form only have text input, so you could remove it. And `bodyParser` doesn't support `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: what about removing `app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '100mb',extended: false }));`?

Comment: same isuue without above line

Comment: @ Jack Yu i checked code again it works with postman  but not with form

Comment: Try to remove `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form.

Comment: No but i found that it has some blocking routes which are blocking form data i removed that and now its working